# Monty Hall Problem with twist

Tags: probability, monty-hall

I have a version of the Monty Hall Problem with a slight twist.

**Classic Setup**

Suppose there are 3 doors to choose from. You have to get the correct door. Once you choose one door, one of the wrong doors that you didn't choose is eliminated. Then you have the choice to switch or not.

In this case it is favorable to switch.

**Twist**

What if the initial probabilities of each door are not the same but p1, p2, and p3, such that p1 < p2 < p3. What would be the best strategy in this case?

Comment: Then always pick door $1$ and switch when given the option. Then you have the probability $p_2+p_3>\frac{2}{3}$ of being correct.

Comment: Is $p_1$ always the probability for the first door we pick, or is there a pre-defined door $1$?

Comment: @Jam no p1 is for door 1, p2 for door 2, and p3 for door 3

Answer (score 5):

Then always pick door $1$ and switch when given the option. Then you have the probability $p_2+p_3>\frac{2}{3}$ of being correct.

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail how you get to p2 + p3 being the probability of it being correct?

Comment: Why was it right to switch in the usual case? The opening of the door doesn't change the fact that the probability that I picked the right door in the first place is $p_1$. So the probability that the other door has the prize is $1-p_1=p_2+p_3$.

Comment: Basically, my strategy always works when the prize is behind door $2$ or $3$. It only fails when it is behind door $1$.

Comment: Note that this is *also* better than the strategy "always choose door 3, never switch", which is kind of interesting (you might imagine the limit $p_3 \to 1$ would break this, but it doesn't because of the "Monty never reveals the prize" rule).